# How to efficiently split a list that has a certain periodicity, into multiple lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example the original list:

`['k','a','b','c','a','d','e','a','b','e','f','j','a','c','a','b']`

We want to split the list into lists started with `'a'` and ended with `'a'`, like the following:

`['a','b','c','a']`

`['a','d','e','a']`

`['a','b','e','f','j','a']`

`['a','c','a']`

The final ouput can also be a list of lists. I have tried a double for loop approach with `'a'` as the condition, but this is inefficient and not pythonic.

Comment: Please edit your code into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one loop:

```
lst = ['k','a','b','c','a','d','e','a','b','e','f','j','a','c','a','b']

out = [[]]
for i in lst:
    if i == 'a':
        out[-1].append(i)
        out.append([])
    out[-1].append(i)
out = out[1:] if out[-1][-1] == 'a' else out[1:-1]
```

Also using `numpy.split`:

```
out = [ary.tolist() + ['a'] for ary in np.split(lst, np.where(np.array(lst) == 'a')[0])[1:-1]]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], ['a', 'd', 'e', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is using `re` (regex)

```
import re

l = ['k','a','b','c','a','d','e','a','b','e','f','j','a','c','a','b']
r = [list(f"a{_}a") for _ in re.findall("(?<=a)[^a]+(?=a)", "".join(l))]
print(r)
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], ['a', 'd', 'e', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can store the indices of `'a'` from the list.

```
oList = ['k','a','b','c','a','d','e','a','b','e','f','j','a','c','a','b']

idx_a = list()

for idx, char in enumerate(oList):
    if char == 'a':
        idx_a.append(idx)
```

Then for every consecutive indices you can get the sub-list and store it in a list

```
ans = [oList[idx_a[x]:idx_a[x + 1] + 1] for x in range(len(idx_a))]
```

You can also get more such lists if you take in-between indices also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single iteration and a simple state machine:

```
original_list = list('kabcadeabefjacab')

multiple_lists = []
for c in original_list:
    if multiple_lists:
        multiple_lists[-1].append(c)
    if c == 'a':
        multiple_lists.append([c])
if multiple_lists[-1][-1] != 'a':
    multiple_lists.pop()

print(multiple_lists)
```

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], ['a', 'd', 'e', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str.split()` to split the list once we `str.join()` it to a string, and then use a f-string to add back the stripped "a"s. Note that even if the list starts/ends with an "a", this the split list will have an empty string representing the substring before the split, so our unpacking logic that discards the first + last subsequences will still work as intended.

```py
def split(data):
    _, *subseqs, _ = "".join(data).split("a")
    return [list(f"a{seq}a") for seq in subseqs]
```

Output:

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> testdata = ['k','a','b','c','a','d','e','a','b','e','f','j','a','c','a','b']
>>> pprint(split(testdata))
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'],
 ['a', 'd', 'e', 'a'],
 ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'a'],
 ['a', 'c', 'a']]
```